# File permissions on uploads directory in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, permissions

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and user profiles have avatars. This is the code I'm using to store the images:

```
if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
    $image = $request->file('avatar');
    if ($image->isValid()) {
        $image->move(public_path() . '/img/avatars/', $user->id . '.png');
    }
}
```

Now my issue is that everything works as intended locally (homestead), but now in production, files simply won't update. The `UploadedFile` class is supposed to throw an exception if anything happens, but it doesn't.

On my own profile however, if I manually remove the image (eg; a blue circle) that corresponds to my user, then upload an image of a red triangle through the website, it places the blue circle image back. /tmp is empty, so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

I've tried all sorts of chmod and chown and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Not 100% sure but could it be that your browser caches the website ?
Have you tried reloding the site with ctrl + F5?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, along with clearing my own cache and wget'ing the file from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with permissions recently when I moved to production, although mine weren't to do with images.

Have you tried doing the following:

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `chmod -R 777 [directory where you are storing the images]`
- `composer dump-autoload`